# Problem Static analysis when importing a large database

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I have a problem with importing a large database. I created a database on `PHPMyAdmin` on my `wamp64` locally and then installed a GLPI with this database. Now that everything is functional I would like to import it on the company's server where I am to set up my GLPI with my database instead of the current one. However I have a problem when I go to the company's PhPMyAdmin I try to import a database but I have an error that tells me""" so I try to zip the file so that it is less heavy or to create the line `$cfg['UploadDir'] ='upload';` but when I do that I have this error :

Error

Static analysis :

1 errors found during the analysis.

```
Unrecognized keyword. (near "ON" at position 25)
```

SQL query: Modify Modify Modify

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = ON;
```

> MySQL replied: Documentation
>
> ## 2006 - MySQL server has gone away
>
> Warning in .\libraries\dbi\DBIMysqli.class.php#261
>    mysqli_query(): MySQL server has gone away

Backtrace

> .\libraries\dbi\DBIMysqli.class.php#261: mysqli_query( object, string
>   INSERT INTO `glpi_crontasklogs` (`id`, `crontasks_id`,
>   `crontasklogs_id`, `date`, `state`, `elapsed`, `volume`, `content`)
>   VALUES (1, 9, 0, \'2019-03-01 15:39:08', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, \'Run mode:
>   CLI\'), (2, 9, 1, \'2019-03-01 15:39:08\', 1, 0.0755451, 0, \'Collect
>   mails from assistance@carpediem.pro
>   ({outlook.office365.com:995/pop/ssl})\n\n\'), (3, 9, 1, \'2019-03-01
>   15:39:08\', 1, 0.645032, 0, \'Number of messages: available=0,
>   retrieved=0, refused=0, errors=0, blacklisted=0\n\n\'), (4, 9, 1,
>   \'2019-03-01 15:39:08\', 2, 1.23802, 0, \'Action completed, no
>   processing required\'), (7, 9, 0, 0, \'2019-03-01 15:40:18\', 0, 0, 0,
>   0, \'Run mode: CLI\'), (8, 9, 7, \'2019-03-01 15:40:18\', 1,
>   0.0849578, 0, \'Mail collection from assistance@carpediem.pro ({outlook.office365.com:995/pop/ssl})\n\n\'), (9, 9, 7, \'2019-03-01
>   15:40:18\', 1, 1.17437, 0, \'Number of messages: available=0,
>   retrieved=0, refused=0, errors=0, blacklisted=0\n\'), (10, 9, 7,
>   \'2019-03-01 15:40:18\', 2, 1.45225, 0, \'Action completed, no
>   processing required\'), (11, 29, 0, \'2019-03-01 15:40:18\', 0, 0, 0,
>   0, \'Run mode: CLI\'), (12, 29, 11, \'2019-03-01 15:40:18\', 2,
>   0.126937, 0, \'Action completed, no processing required\'), (15, 9, 0, 0, \'2019-03-01 15:41:07\', 0, 0, 0, 0, \'Run mode: CLI\'), (16, 9,
>   15, \'2019-03-01 15:41:07\', 1, 0.0819528, 0, \'Collect mails from
>   assistance@carpediem.pro ({outlook.office365.com:995/pop/ssl})\n\n\'),
>   (17, 9, 15, \'2019-03-01 15:41:07\', 1, 0.995655, 0, \'Number of
>   messages: available=0, retrieved=0, refused=0, errors=0,
>   blacklisted=0\n\n\'), (18, 9, 15, \'2019-03-01 15:41:07\', 2, 1.05668,
>   0, \'Action completed, no processing required\'), (21, 9, 0, 0,
>   \'2019-03-01 15:42:17\', 0, 0, 0, 0, \'Run mode: CLI\'), (22, 9, 21,
>   \'2019-03-01 15:42:17\', 1, 0.0884838, 0, \'Collect mails from
>   assistance@carpediem.pro ({outlook.office365.com:995/pop/ssl})\n\n\'),
>   (23, 9, 21, \'2019-03-01 15:42:17\', 1, 1.15658, 0, \'Number of
>   messages: available=0, retrieved=0, refused=0, errors=0,
>   blacklisted=0\n\n\'), (24, 9, 21, \'2019-03-01 15:42:17\', 2, 1.20123,
>   0, \'Action completed, no processing required\'), (25, 17, 0, 0,
>   \'2019-03-01 15:42:17\', 0, 0, 0, 0, \'Run mode: CLI\'), (26, 17, 25,
>   \'2019-03-01 15:42:17\', 2, 0.102944, 0, \'Action completed, no
>   processing required\'), (31, 9, 0, 0, \'2019-03-01 15:43:05\', 0, 0,
>   0, 0, \'Run mode: CLI\'), (32, 9, 31, \'2019-03-01 15:43:05\', 1,
>   0.0800591, 0, \'Collect mails from assistance@carpediem.pro ({outlook.office365.com:995/pop/ssl})\n\n\'), (33, 9, 31, \'2019-03-01
>   15:43:05\', 1, 1.04019, 0, \'Number of messages: available=0,
>   retrieved=0, rejected=0, errors=0, blacklisted=0\n\n\'), (34, 9, 31,
>   \'2019-03-01 15:43:05\', 2, 1.05323, 0, \'Action completed, no
>   processing required\'), (35, 23, 0, 0, \'2019-03-01 15:43:05\', 0, 0,
>   0, 0, \'Run mode: CLI\'), (36, 23, 35, \'2019-03-01 15:43:05\', 2,
>   0.117135, 0, \'Action completed, no processing required'), (39, 9, 0, 0, \'2019-03-01 15:44:16\', 0, 0, 0, 0, \'Run mode: CLI\'), (40, 9,
>   39, \'2019-03-01 15:44:16\', 1, 0.0911481, 0, \'Collect emails from
>   assistance@carpediem.pro ({outlook.office365.com:995/pop/ssl})\n\n\'),
>   (41, 9, 39, \'2019-03-01 15:44:16\', 1, 1.14253, 0, \'Number of
>   messages: available=0, retrieved=0, refused=0, errors=0,
>   blacklisted=0\n\n\'), (42, 9, 39, \'2019-03-01 15:44:16\', 2, 1.18234,
>   0, \'Action completed, no processing required\'), (45, 9, 0, 0,
>   \'2019-03-01 15:45:03\', 0, 0, 0, 0, \'Run mode: CLI\'), (46, 9, 45,
>   \'2019-03-01 15:45:03\', 1, 0.053148, 0, \'Collect mails from
>   assistance@carpediem.pro ({outlook.office365.com:995/pop/ssl})\n\n\'),
>   (47, 9, 45, \'2019-03-01 15:45:45:03\', 1, 0.933414, 0, \'Number of
>   messages: available=0, retrieved=0, refused=0, errors=0,
>   blacklisted=0\n\n\'), (48, 9, 45, \'2019-03-01 15:45:03\', 2,
>   0.941932, 0, \'Action completed, no processing required\'), (49, 29, 0, \'2019-03-01 15:45:03\', 0, 0, 0, 0, \'Run mod.....
>
> .\libraries\plugins\import\ImportSql.class.php#161:
>   PMA_importRunQuery( string 'DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `glpi_crontasks`',
>   string 'DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `glpi_crontasks`', boolean false, array,
>   ) .\import.php#641: ImportSql->doImport(array)

Can you help me because I don't know where the problem comes from and I don't know how to fix it

Answer (score 0):

Using phpmyadmin to export and import a large database might be suboptimal.
Use mysqldump command to backup and mysql to restore. There are plenty of examples over the net. Just a head start:

Backup

```
mysqldump --add-drop-table --complete-insert --extended-insert --quote-names --host=localhost --user=root --password=YOURPASSWORD glpi > c:\glpibackup\glpi_mysqldump.sql
```

Restore

```
mysql -u root -p YOURPASSWORD < c:\glpibackup\glpi_mysqldump.sql
```